# Can't access data function properties from methods in Vue.Js Component

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying to use an input to get a welcome message by writing the username in the input and putting it in the h3 so I'm trying to set a data property which is `username: ''` but when I'm trying to use it from methods, I get an error saying that `'username' is not defined`, This is the code:

```
<template>
 <aside>
  <h3>Welcome {{ username }}</h3>
  <form action="">
   <h3>Welcome to smart-z todolist</h3>
   <p>Please write down your name</p>
   <div>
    <input type="text" :v-model="username" id="userName" />
    <button type="submit" @click.prevent="addUser">Done</button>
   </div>
  </form>
 </aside>
</template>

<script>
 export default {
  name: "AsideSect",
  data() {
   return {
    username: "",
   };
  },
  methods: {
   addUser: () => {
   console.log(username);
  },
 },
 };
</script>
```

If anyone can help, please drop down you answer and thank you!

Comment: it should be `console.log(this.username)`.  In template code you don't need to use `this`, but in your script code you do.

Comment: @yoduh Thanks for your help but that didn't really work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 issues here:

1. When using `v-model`, you do not put `: (colon)`. The input tag should look something like this: `<input type="text" v-model="username" id="userName" />`
2. `addUser` is an arrow function and `username` is out of its scope. To access `username`, create a normal function and call `this.username` like the following:`addUser() { console.log(this.username); }`

[Find the working code here](https://jsfiddle.net/sharitu/3tk4dbxn/5/)